# Audio element error in Chrome: no "ended" event and negative time elapsed

Tags: google-chrome, html5-audio

I have the following HTML and JS:

```
<script>
  function onEnded(ev) {
    window.location.reload();
  }
</script>

<audio id="audio-element" controls autoplay onended="onEnded();">
  <source src="/stream/3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
```

For some MP3 streams, this works perfectly; playback starts and when the audio track ends `onEnded` is called. For others, playback starts fine and the audio file is played, but then right at the end the elapsed time counter goes extremely negative, the `ended` event never fires and `audio_element.ended` returns `false`. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Chrome audio player error]

This happens in Chrome, but not Safari or Firefox, which behave as expected. Any idea what I can do in Chrome to make the `ended` event fire?

Answer (score 1):

you must be sure that your server accept range transfer, otherwise chrome will not be able to evalutate time correctly and so 'ended'  event will not fire.

you can check this by doing:

```
 curl --head -X GET http://yourmp3location
```

if you see:

```
 Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

then is ok, otherwise fix your server

In addition, Have you tried this?

```
<audio id="audio-element" controls autoplay onended="onEnded">
```

I had changed the onended attribute so that the browser don't evalutate onended function while rendering your page.

You can also remove the onended attribute to the tag audio and add this at the bottom of your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById("audio-element").addEventListener('ended', function(ev) {
       window.location.reload();
   }, false);
</script>
```

Comment: For reference, development servers such as `python -m http.server` and `django runserver` lacks the header

Answer (score 1):

We had a very similar problem with Chrome - this browser doesn't emit onended events in new Chrome 64 (and beta 65, canary 66) but when we rebuild MP3 with stream this problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when attempting to handle audio ending on mobile Chrome: 
When I created an audio element via javascript (via GWT), the onended event would never fire for me.  I was able to get working however:  my issue was that it was not attached to the DOM (if I'm understanding the structure correctly), but was floating in javascript limbo.  Once I set the element to display: none and added it to a page element, my onended handler works correctly.

tl;dr
if your element isn't directly attached to a DOM element, try hiding it and attaching it (anywhere really).